# Error in displaying array values in jsp through jstl

Tags: java, arrays, jsp

I have a two dimensional array whcich holds values from resultset as:

```
 while (rs.next())
                {
                    for( j=0; j<3; j++)
                    {
                            a[i][j] = rs.getString(j+1);
                    }

                    i++;
                }
              return a;
```

I display it in jsp page as-

```
<select name="ref_name">
<c:forEach var="aff" items="${obj.connect()}">
<option value="${aff}">${aff}</option>
</c:forEach>
 </select>
```

Where obj is the bean id and connect is the method which return String[][] .But when I run it I get values as [Ljava.lang.String@381a9c.
I know this is the reference of array which is displayed but not value.How to correct it?

Comment: @Roman C there it was Map and my problem was not solved by Map so I tried with array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to iterate the `Map` , you need to access its key and value,

```
<select name="ref_name">
   <c:forEach var="aff" items="${obj.connect()}">
      <option value="${aff.key}">${aff.value}</option>
   </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Will print the values from the map.

**Edit** :

As per your edit in the question to access the `2D` array , just iterate the array within the array

```
 <select name="ref_name">
    <c:forEach var="aff" items="${obj.connect()}" >
        <c:forEach var="secondVar" items="${aff}" >
            <option value="${secondVar}">${secondVar}</option> // printing the value here
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
 </select>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I'm not trying to iterate over Map,Its array here.

Comment: But in your question , you mentioned _connect is the method which return linkedhash map_ ?

Comment: I edited,my mistake.

Comment: Check my update and let me know for any issues

Comment: ,yup it worked ,but I want that my entire row from resultset should be in one line in dropdown list.I tried with array ,list and map but of no use.Can you suggest me ,how to do that

Comment: You could try it with the `List` if your value and label are same . else go for a map if they are different. consider upvote and accept if it helped you

Comment: I tried with list and map ,My values are different